# Can Birt be used on a none Java web application?

Tags: birt

I am currently doing a research about reporting tools and particulary focusing on **Birt** only I have noticed that it is ment for **Java web applications**, I can't find enough resources on Birt integration with other technologies such as **.Net** or **Nodejs**, does any body have links or resources in which I can see an example of how to integrate Birt in web applications other than Java ?

Comment: Birt needs to be deployed as Java application. But you can use REST API between report design files and backend services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST or JavaScriptAPI as mentioned before to display where you want. You can use JavaComponents or the BIRT runtime to generate HTML that can also be displayed using your preferred server. The engines require Java but you can decide how to interact with the engines or how to serve the content.

Comment: Do you have an exemple of how I can achieve that ?

Comment: What products are you working with... opensource only or some commercial? Also, did you want API or just using the runtime?

Comment: I am using BIRT Report Designer (RCP) , currently only open source products, i'm trying to understand how it works and how can I use it in a web application using both API and the runtime , now when I did researches i found that i should deploy Birt into Tomcat Apache but i don't know what's the next step.

Comment: Also when i run birt from the designer (Run -> as HTML) I want to know if birt has to be in the same machine as my application ? can I publish the reports in other non local machines ?