# How can I Integrate Birt Reports which i have created via Birt report eclipse with React based application

Tags: java, reactjs, report, backend, birt

1.I have created reports using Birt Reporting  tool via eclipse Now I want to integrate these reports in my Application based on React as front-end and java as Back-end. so that i can open reports directly from application.
2.can anyone tell me the steps to integrate with my application ?
3. Do i need to  made changes in java side code for integration.

4. I am new to this can anyone help me out from where i can start .

Please let me know if you need more details .
Thank You In Advance !!

Comment: Have you seen these suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944608